# Как сделать появление блока по атрибуту(jquery)?

Tags: jquery

Всем привет.
Прошу помощи т.к. не получается реализовать самому.
Вот код, после объяснение того, что надо:

```
<a href="#" id="block1" class="block-btn" style="top: 32px; left: 593px;"></a>

<div class="hide-block" data-block-visible="block1" style="top: 20px; left: 447px;">
    <button class="custom-close"></button>
</div>
```

И так, нужно чтобы при нажатии на ссылку по id находился блок с data-block-visible и соответственно выводил его, дальше подумаю как, либо fadeIn, либо же добавлением класса, это сам модифицирую. И чтобы по нажатии на кнопку окно пропадало. Окон таких будет несколько и желательно, чтобы не было конфликта в закрывании.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Логику написал, остальное допишете сами.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.block-btn', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var block = $('div[data-block-visible="' + id + '"]');
  block.fadeIn(); // some operation with block
  console.log('clicked on #' + id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" id="block1" class="block-btn" style="top: 32px; left: 593px;">Link</a>

<div class="hide-block" data-block-visible="block1" style="top: 20px; left: 447px;">
    <button class="custom-close"></button>
</div>

<a href="#" id="block2" class="block-btn" style="top: 32px; left: 593px;">Link</a>

<div class="hide-block" data-block-visible="block2" style="top: 20px; left: 447px;">
    <button class="custom-close"></button>
</div>

<a href="#" id="block3" class="block-btn" style="top: 32px; left: 593px;">Link</a>

<div class="hide-block" data-block-visible="block3" style="top: 20px; left: 447px;">
    <button class="custom-close"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, это работает. Но нужно еще чтобы при нажатии на кнопку внутри была функция скрытия. Можно как-то реализовать?

Comment: [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

Comment: куда это написать?

Comment: Блок, который скрывать хотите `$('.block').hide()`. Читайте документацию.

Comment: Спасибо. Докостылял и все работает =)